# Equivalent of method date.valueOf () JavaScript with PHP

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp, strtotime

I have this script in JavaScript:

```
var dt = new Date();
var intDt = dt.valueOf();
console.log(intDt); // 1504100049524
```

I want to covert this to PHP but in my surprise the result is not the same.
This is my PHP script:

```
$dt = date(DATE_RFC2822);
$intDt = strtotime($dt);
echo($intDt); //1504100049
```

I need this to calculate the moon phase, fraction and angle.

The calculus of the phase, fraction and angle of the moon works fine in my js script. But the result of my PHP is different of the JavaScript because of this.

Comment: Time with microseconds can be received with `microtime(true)`

Comment: See [this answer](/a/20502368/5764553). The numbers aren't as different as you think. The PHP is roughly 1000x the JavaScript number because it works in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: If you want this for calculating moon phases, etc it's far better to use DateTime objects that are timezone and daylight savings aware than simple unix timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's time functions return the time in seconds since the unix epoch not milliseconds like JS. You either need to divide the JS time by 1000 and discard the remainder or multiply the PHP time by 1000. [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) with the second parameter set to true could be used but it only retrieves the current time.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `getTimestamp()` will give you the UNIX timestamp, i.e. number of **seconds** since January 1st, 1970.

More info here: [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Javascript `valueOf()` will give you the number of **milliseconds** since the same date.

More here: [Date​.prototype​.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)

With those in mind here's a snippet in javascript:

```
var jsdt = new Date('2018-08-18')
undefined
jsdt.valueOf()
1534550400000
```

And here's how you would do the "same" in PHP:

```
$external = "08/18/2018 00:00:00";
$format = "m/d/Y H:i:s";
$dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $external);
echo $dateobj->getTimestamp()*1000; // 1534550400000
```